# phpMyAdmin set 'INSERT DELAYED statements' not checked

Tags: phpmyadmin

Is there a way to the INSERT DELAYED by default to NOT be checked?

Currently it defaults to checked and causes this error if we forget to uncheck it: #1616 - DELAYED option not supported for table ...

Had a quick look in the code but so confusing couldn't find the HTML for the checkbox, if there is no option to disable the checked checkbox I want to just modify the code but can't even find that. Looked in: libraries/display_export.inc.php which points to PMA_getHtmlForExportOptions but still non the wiser as to how to modify this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about Export options, yes, set this in your config.inc.php: $cfg['Export']['sql_delayed'] = false;